# Using pdb while running a module

Tags: python-3.x, pdb

I know that we can use python debugger while running a python script like this.

`python -m pdb script.py`

But how do I use it when I am already running a module like this.

`python -m script`

Comment: Do you own the module? If so, you could just `import pdb` and set a breakpoint directly in your code.

Comment: Yeah that is true. But I was looking for an easier command line method to run the debugger instead of manually inserting the breakpoints.

Comment: Yea, thats fair enough. But to my knowledge, your best bet would be to just try to either (a) run the source without making it a module, or (b) Find the location of the file you intend to run on your filesystem and run it yourself directly with the -pdb flag.

Comment: python -m pdb -m script